# Why is serialize() breaking my update?

Tags: php, mysql

I can not understand why this code is breaking. I am sending a jQuery array to a php script.

jQuery:

```
var someArray = ["elementone", "elementtwo", "elementthree"];
$.post(addToDB.php, {thisVariable: someArray}, function (data) {alert data;});
```

PHP:

```
$someArray = $_POST['thisVariable'];
$query = 'INSERT INTO someTable SET someColumn = "' . $someArray. '"';
```

Here's my problem; I can echo the serialized array:

```
echo serialize($someArray);
```

but if I try to update the DB with *serialize($someArray)* instead of *$someArray* the code breaks and nothing is updated. If It try to echo or update *$someArray*, I get:

```
Array
```

If I echo *$someArray[0]* I get the appropriate element.

What am I missing? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick guess ... missing *escaping* ?

Comment: Please consider using parameterized queries, as it makes escaping hassles go away, while also protecting you against SQL injection attacks.  As currently written, I suspect that this application is vulnerable to such attacks.

Comment: not to mention your elementthree in your array definition is missing a leading "

Comment: If you let yourself be led into using parameterized queries without due research, be advised, that you lose access to the `IN ( ... )` construct

Comment: nothing is broken. you need `print_r` or some loop construct to "echo" an array.

Comment: @EugenRieck: No you don't, you just have to bind a parameter for each value in the `IN ( ... )` construct, and build that part of the statement by `implode(',', array_keys($inParams))` or similar.

Comment: @Kris ... which means, that you need a different SQL query text for each possible number of elements in the `IN( ... )` list. This qualifies for "losing access to the construct"

Comment: @EugenRieck, parameterized != prepared. "I can only show you the door. You're the one that has to walk through it."

Comment: @Kris - and we talked about parameterized, not prepared.

Comment: @EugenRieck: then how is concatenating a small part of a statement more prohibitive than concatenating the whole thing. you're not making much sense to me.

Comment: Concatenating defeats the purpose of parametrized queries - so as a matter of fact, you have to chose between parameterized queries and unfetted access to the `IN( ... )` statement. Denying is lying. In many cases, this will be an acceptable trade-off - I personally accept it in most cases. But it is simply wrong to propose parameterized queries without mentioning, that they very markedly reduce your SQL vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are going about building sql statements in an entirely inappropriate way, the real issue you're having trouble with is that you are trying to `echo` an array. that cannot be done. Alos, you cannot append an array to a string using the concatenation operator (`.`). You'll have to encode ([serialize](http://php.net/serialize)/[unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize)) the array for storage; or normalize the database...

You could use [print_r](http://php.net/print_r), [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump), [var_export](http://php.net/var_export) or a [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) construct to do that though.

Really though, use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php); you'll be so immensely much better off.

Comment: I will certainly research and implement parameterized queries, however in the interim, should print (serialize($query))

Comment: allow me to store the serialized array as a string?

Comment: I can echo the serialized array; why can't I store it as a string?

Comment: you have to `serialize` it when you insert it and `unserialize` it after you read it back from the database. Also; `serialize`-ing in place may break your query because the serialized string ends up containing unescaped quotes etc. you need to escape those.

Comment: Ah ok. I will try escaping.

Comment: Thanks to Kris, Eugen, and shiplu for your answers. Escaping was my issue. I am also now looking at the security issues of my code. You guys are much appreciated.